# How can I correct the mutate and filter errors in my R function

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, magrittr

I have function that takes a dataframe and two other variables (horse and race_date) as inputs.  The horse and race_date are utilized to filter the dataframe passed the function and then a summarise function is applied to calculate the desired output.  When I test the function stand-alone and outside of the pipes everything works fine but when I try to run the function from within a mutate function and the pipes I get the following error message:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `split_Lt`.
x Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
x Input `..1` must be of size 1, not size 18.
i Input `..1` is `Horse == horse & NewSplit == "LT Races" & race_date < date`.
i The error occurred in group 2: split = "A BIT OF BOTH_var106_Track: CD".
i Input `split_Lt` is `getsplit_LT(splits, horse, race_date)`.
i The error occurred in group 2: split = "A BIT OF BOTH_var106_Track: CD".
```

Here is the function:

```
getsplit_LT <- function(df, horse, date){

  kpi <- df %>% 
    filter(Horse == horse & NewSplit == "LT Races" & race_date < date) %>% 
    group_by(split) %>% 
    summarise_if(is.numeric, sum) %>% 
    mutate(TopAvgB = ((E + 3.439) /(R+3.439 + 25.69))) %>% 
    select(TopAvgB) 
    
  x = if(is.data.frame(kpi) && nrow(kpi)==0){0}else{kpi[[1]]}
   
  return(x)
 
}
```

Here's the code I tried to run:

```
df <- df %>%  
  mutate(split_Lt = getsplit_LT(splits, horse, race_date))
```

Here is the dput data:

```
structure(list(horse = c("A BIT OF BOTH", "A BIT OF BOTH", "A BIT OF BOTH", 
"A BIT OF BOTH", "A BIT OF BOTH", "A BIT OF BOTH", "A BIT OF BOTH", 
"A BIT OF BOTH", "A BIT OF BOTH", "A BIT OF BOTH", "A BIT OF BOTH", 
"A BIT OF BOTH", "A BIT OF BOTH", "A BIT OF BOTH", "A BIT OF BOTH", 
"A BIT OF BOTH", "A BIT OF BOTH", "A BIT OF BOTH"), race_date = structure(c(17802, 
17906, 17941, 17969, 18006, 18062, 18091, 18183, 18183, 18226, 
18244, 18286, 18454, 18502, 18546, 18581, 18601, 18664), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-18L), groups = structure(list(horse = "A BIT OF BOTH", .rows = structure(list(
    1:18), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", 
"list"))), row.names = 1L, class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

```
structure(list(split = c("A BIT OF BOTH_var102B_LifeTime: Life", 
"A BIT OF BOTH_var102B_LifeTime: Life", "A BIT OF BOTH_var102B_LifeTime: Life", 
"A BIT OF BOTH_var102B_LifeTime: Life", "A BIT OF BOTH_var102B_LifeTime: Life", 
"A BIT OF BOTH_var102B_LifeTime: Life", "A BIT OF BOTH_var102B_LifeTime: Life", 
"A BIT OF BOTH_var102B_LifeTime: Life", "A BIT OF BOTH_var102B_LifeTime: Life", 
"A BIT OF BOTH_var102B_LifeTime: Life", "A BIT OF BOTH_var102B_LifeTime: Life", 
"A BIT OF BOTH_var102B_LifeTime: Life", "A BIT OF BOTH_var102B_LifeTime: Life", 
"A BIT OF BOTH_var102B_LifeTime: Life", "A BIT OF BOTH_var102B_LifeTime: Life", 
"A BIT OF BOTH_var102B_LifeTime: Life", "A BIT OF BOTH_var102B_LifeTime: Life", 
"A BIT OF BOTH_var102B_LifeTime: Life", "A BIT OF BOTH_var106_Track: CD", 
"A BIT OF BOTH_var106_Track: CT", "A BIT OF BOTH_var106_Track: DE", 
"A BIT OF BOTH_var106_Track: FG", "A BIT OF BOTH_var106_Track: GP", 
"A BIT OF BOTH_var106_Track: GP", "A BIT OF BOTH_var106_Track: GP", 
"A BIT OF BOTH_var106_Track: GP", "A BIT OF BOTH_var106_Track: GP", 
"A BIT OF BOTH_var106_Track: GP", "A BIT OF BOTH_var106_Track: GP", 
"A BIT OF BOTH_var106_Track: GP", "A BIT OF BOTH_var106_Track: KE", 
"A BIT OF BOTH_var106_Track: MT", "A BIT OF BOTH_var106_Track: MT", 
"A BIT OF BOTH_var106_Track: OT", "A BIT OF BOTH_var106_Track: PX", 
"A BIT OF BOTH_var106_Track: PX", "A BIT OF BOTH_var107_Surface: Dirt", 
"A BIT OF BOTH_var107_Surface: Dirt", "A BIT OF BOTH_var107_Surface: Dirt", 
"A BIT OF BOTH_var107_Surface: Dirt", "A BIT OF BOTH_var107_Surface: Dirt", 
"A BIT OF BOTH_var107_Surface: Dirt", "A BIT OF BOTH_var107_Surface: Dirt", 
"A BIT OF BOTH_var107_Surface: Dirt", "A BIT OF BOTH_var107_Surface: Dirt", 
"A BIT OF BOTH_var107_Surface: Dirt", "A BIT OF BOTH_var107_Surface: Dirt", 
"A BIT OF BOTH_var107_Surface: Dirt", "A BIT OF BOTH_var107_Surface: Dirt", 
"A BIT OF BOTH_var107_Surface: Synth", "A BIT OF BOTH_var107_Surface: Turf", 
"A BIT OF BOTH_var107_Surface: Turf", "A BIT OF BOTH_var107_Surface: Turf"
```

Comment: Do you mean to pass the lower-case `horse` column of `df` into your function along with the `splits` data frame? That seems strange. Could you post just a few rows of sample input in your question using `dput()` so it's copy/pasteable, and also show the desired result for those rows? It will be clearer with a small example, and nice to keep things self-contained.

Comment: @GregorThomas  yes, I did mean to pass the lower-case horse.  I will give dput() a try - first time hearing about it. Thanks.

Comment: `dput(df[1:10, ])`, for example, gives a copy/pasteable version of the first 10 rows of `df`, with all structure and class information included. It's the preferred way to post sample data for R.

Comment: Just as an aside, the data.frame on your github repository has non-standard unicode whitespace. `A BIT OF BOTH` has `\u00a0` instead of ` `.

Comment: @IanCampbell thanks, I've provided dput() data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is with the `purrr::pmap` function which applies a function on a data.frame rowwise.

```
library(tidyverse)
pmap(df, ~ getsplit_LT(splits, horse = .x, date = .y))
[[1]]
[1] 0.2156712

[[2]]
[1] 0

[[3]]
[1] 0.1070373

[[4]]
[1] 0.1339914

[[5]]
[1] 0.1593659
...
```

Or back with the original data.frame:

```
bind_cols(df,kpi = pmap_dbl(df, ~ getsplit_LT(splits, horse = .x, date = .y)))
# A tibble: 18 x 3
   horse         race_date    kpi
   <chr>         <date>     <dbl>
 1 A BIT OF BOTH 2020-09-28 0.216
 2 A BIT OF BOTH 2020-01-10 0    
 3 A BIT OF BOTH 2020-02-14 0.107
 4 A BIT OF BOTH 2020-03-14 0.134
 5 A BIT OF BOTH 2020-04-20 0.159
 6 A BIT OF BOTH 2020-06-15 0.183
 7 A BIT OF BOTH 2020-07-14 0.227
...
```

Data:

```
splits <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Handicappr/Rstudio_test_project/main/splits.csv")
df <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Handicappr/Rstudio_test_project/main/df.csv")
splits %>% mutate(race_date = as.Date(race_date,"%m/%d/%y")) -> splits
df %>% mutate(race_date = as.Date(race_date,"%m/%d/%y")) -> df
```